# Is it common for the console to accept some commands but reject others?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I am trying to use the console in 2.7.2; the console comes up and can do some simple commands, such as adding money with "cash." However, the commands prov_rel and province_religion do not seem to work.

```
prov_rel 112 hellenic_pagan
```

should change the religion of a province.

Instead, it always returns:

```
unknown command
```

I have tried with several different saved games.

Also:

When I enter

```
help province_religion
```

it returns

```
Command not found
```

Similarly,

```
nextsong
```

works correctly but

```
listsongs
```

does not work and returns

```
Unknown command
```

I don't know whether some combination of DLCs or other factors has disabled some commands but not others. There doesn't seem to be any wiki page or forum discussion about cases where the console works for some commands but not for others. Is this fixable?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem with 2.7 that does not appear in 3.0.  It seems likely that no installation of 2.7 can run all of the listed console commands.